# Load another website with CNAME

Tags: .htaccess, server, dns, cname

I'm trying to load another website of mine using CNAME record

I have a website demo.maindomain.com where I keep all my files and I want that to be accessed from demo.anotherwebsite.com

So for example, if someone tries to access demo.anotherwebsite.com/link1, the content from demo.maindomain.com/link1 would actually load but the url remain to demo.anotherwebsite.com/link1

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo.anotherwebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://demo.maindomain.com/$1 [P]
```

this redirected demo.anotherwebsite.com to demo.maindomain.com in address bar

Is there anyway we can do this with htaccess or cname or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `[P]` flag only works if mod_proxy is loaded and you have the options turned on to proxy from an htaccess file. This kind of solution a poor solution though. What you need to do is point the DNS of anotherwebsite.com to point to the same IP Address as "maindomain.com". You can do this with an A record or a CNAME (with the CNAME, you can indicate "demo.maindomain.com".

This will all depend on who you have your domain registered with.

- GoDaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236
- Bluehost: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/cname
- Cloudflare: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-